# where do I get ninject that is asp.net mvc friendly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

Ninject's site only has version 1.0

where can I get the one that has ninject.framework.mvc libriaries?

Answer (score 2):

**How to use Ninject2 with ASP.NET MVC**
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/14/how-to-use-ninject-2-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Comment: This would be actually better: http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/08/14/how-to-use-ninject-2-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use NuGet and add Ninject.MVC3

```
PM> Install-Package Ninject.MVC3
```